# can I connect two modems and comunicate on two side

Tags: modem

I just wondering how modems work.

I know the process of "modulation" and "demodulation".

So I wanto know is "demodulation" are simple revese of "modulation" in *real world*.

The PC can got an IP address when connect as **type 1**

What will happen when I connect them like **type 2**?

> **type 1 :**
>
> [PC] ================= [router]
>
> **type 2 :**
>
> [PC] === [m] ------- [m] === [router]
>
> [m] : modem(exactly same)
>
> === : Ethernet cable
>
> --- : DSL cable *(phone line, maybe optical fiber, or something else?)*

ISP has a large number of model, Is them same thing as the one in my home(but with diffrent size/speed/price...etc)? Or it's completely different thing?

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to do here.  What sort of wire is "===" and what sort of wire is "-----"?

Comment: are we talking dialup modems or something more modern?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, your type 1 and type 2 connections will function identically.

As long as your modems satisfactorily communicate with each other, which shouldn't be a problem as long as both modems comply with accepted standards, they will be transparent to the PC and router.

Comment: Ah, but the devil is in the details.  I seriously doubt that two DSL customer-end modems will communicate with each other.

Comment: If there is "customer-end" modems, then the "ISP-side" is different with "customer-end" one?

Comment: @GongT yes, usually on the ISP side there will be a [DSLAM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_subscriber_line_access_multiplexer), two consumer modems will *likely* not have the internal firmware to talk to another consumer modem, however the modem's firmware may be flashable or configurable to allow it, but I doubt you will find one that would work with default configurations.